# How can I make my Azure logic app portable

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Azure logic app in Azure Portal which uses Azure functions and Azure Service Bus. I want to deliver this whole logic app to client so that he can configure it in his Azure Subscription. How can I push my Azure Logic App to GitHub or any other place so that I can make it distribute able. So that anyone can deploy it in his Azure subscription or resource group. Help!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make an Azure Deployment Template.  If you create the logic app within the [Visual Studio tools](http://aka.ms/logicapps-visualstudio) it's created for you with the `logicapp.json` file - we are working right now to let you import a logic app into visual studio.  For now you can still create a template with a PowerShell command.  Details on creating a deployment template can be found [in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-create-deploy-template).

You'll also need to add the Azure Function to the same template.  You can see an example of a template that deploys both a logic app and an azure function in the same template [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-logic-app-transform-function) - let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the template from the Azure Portal.

Goto Resource Groups > Select your Resource Group > Click on Automation Scrips.

You will see the Deployment template - which will help you to deploy all the resources in the Resource Group.

If you just want the Function to be exported, Go to the Function > Click on Automation Scripts.

You can follow http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/03/azure-arm-template-import-and-export-templates-from-portal/ to know more about Importing and Exporting Azure Templates.